# How to set a variable after a target been made?

Tags: c++, makefile

I have ***.cc*** and **.proto** files in a directory. ***.proto** files are used to generate **.cc** and **.h** files.

Now I want **$(SRC)** have all .cc files including those generated. How?

```
PROTOS = $(wildcard *.proto)

SRC = $(wildcard *.cc)
OBJS = $(patsubst %.cc,%.o,$(SRC))

all: proto $(OBJS)

proto: $(PROTOS)
    protoc --cpp_out=. $(PROTOS)
```

Comment: if your proto files generate files with the same name then you can do `SRC=$(patsubst %.proto,%.cc,$(PROTOS))` kind of thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. Make determines the list of rules to be executed before it executes any.

Long answer: you can, but you must have Make run itself a second time:

```
PROTOS = $(wildcard *.proto)

SRC = $(wildcard *.cc)
OBJS = $(patsubst %.cc,%.o,$(SRC))

all: proto
    $(MAKE) objs

proto: $(PROTOS)
    protoc --cpp_out=. $(PROTOS)

objs: $(OBJS)
```